# Why do Python threads print to console in Mac but don't on Ubuntu

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, ubuntu, python-asyncio

I'm trying out this hybrid method of running async browsers:

```
import asyncio
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)

options = Options()
options.headless = True

def scrape(url, *, loop):
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, scraper, url)

def scraper(url: str):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    print(driver.title)
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.close()

urls = [
    'https://example.com',
    'https://wikipedia.org'
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for url in urls:
    scrape(url, loop=loop)
```

So, when I run it on Mac, function `scraper` prints without issues to the terminal. However, when I run the same code on a Ubuntu laptop, it prints nothing. I have event wondered if the function throws an exception, but found no error messages. Does anyone know why this happens and how to go about solving it?

Comment: If possible please please provide more details regarding your setup: what version of Mac are you running? what version of ubuntu are you running? what version of python are you using in 1st and 2nd case?

Comment: how did you run it on Ubuntu? Any chance you are redirecting the output somewhere else?

Comment: @Daweo mac is BigSur 11.6 and Ubuntu is 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I'm running it as `python3 script_name.py`. In case it's important, am runing it in a separate virtualenvironment.